# How to set 2 auto increment id in table[Magento 2]

Tags: magento2, table, auto-increment

is there any way to create 2 auto increment id in same table?When im trying to create using db_schema, error showing that only primary key id can get this auto increment.is there any other ways?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44132210/12004981

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<table name="declarative_table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id_column1" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id_column2" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Entity Id"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="severity" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Severity code"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Title"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="time_occurred"  comment="Time of event"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id_column1"/>
            <column name="id_column2"/>
        </constraint>
   </table>
```

it's working fine. check the screenshot

[image]

Comment: no,its not working for me.

Comment: update your schema code in question

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I added the multiple increment id in the table and it's work like charm:

add the desired column in the database you want to add in the increment :

```
<column xsi:type="varchar" name="id" nullable="true" length="255" comment="ID"/>
```

and then in the model use this code :

```
               $collection = $model->getCollection();
                $collection->getSelect()->order('id DESC');
                $collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
                $lastItem = $collection->getFirstItem();
                $lastId = $lastItem->getId();

                // Increment the ID
                $newId = $lastId + 1;
                $model->setData('id', $newId);
                $model->save();
```